# Is changing the binding time possible in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I was wondering if it is possible to change the time that a binding updates the controls that are bound to it.  For instance, I'm working with a TextBox, which is updating every time a key is pressed, but I would like it to update when it loses focus instead.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show use some of your xaml, I'm intrigued by how you manage to get this behaviour from a TextBox in the first place??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this surprises me because I thought the TextBox was the one control which held back its updating of the binding source until the focused moved elsewhere, a small test confirms this.

Anyhow, lets imagine that it does normally update on every key press or some control like it does.

A general solution would be to take "manual" control of source updating.  You can do this with the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property setting to "Explicit".  This means the source of the binding will only by updated when your code explicitly calls the `UpdateSource` method on the `BindingExpression` for the binding with the `TextProperty` of the "TextBox".

You could perform this explicit update then in an event handler for the "TextBox" `LostFocus` event.

For Example, in an initial UserControl add this xaml:-

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox x:Name="Target" />
    <TextBox x:Name="Source" Grid.Row="1"
        Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=Target, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" LostFocus="Source_LostFocus"/>
</Grid>
```

Now in the code-behind the event handler looks like this:-

```
    private void Source_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((TextBox)sender).GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're trying to do, but here's a suggestion:

Remove the binding and then add an event for your textbox for LostFocus: ie.

```
private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  textBox.Text = originallyBindedValue;
}
```

Not as clean as through XAML but you should be able to get your desired behavior.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of doing that, but I was hoping to avoid doing it in the code behind.